# My WebView does strange things

Tags: android

Why when I click a link in the page loaded in the WebView in my application it opens it in the default browser (or if I have more than one browser, it asks me to choose one of them)? In the main.xml I just set an id, a height and a width. I have only the WebView. In the java code I just get the WebView that's in the main file with the findViewById, I set javascripts enabled with wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); and I load the page in the onCreate method. I know for sure the webpage I load doesn't contain any strange link that may cause my problem because it's my website, ad I made it. I load the page with this code wb.loadUrl("http://www.ciprianis.it");

Comment: You probably didnot override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method in your class for the webview client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override this method and load the URL in the WebView in a custom WebViewClient.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new LinkWebViewClient());

private class LinkWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```